# Converting Data to Binary in order to post it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am building an application where I need to build post data manually. But in this post data, there is an image binary data. So before posting it, the post data should look like this:

```
------------------------------8cc097679560ebc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mode";

test
------------------------------8cc097679560ebc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cropped";

false
------------------------------8cc097679560ebc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Image"; filename="C:\Temp\image_front1.jpg" Content-Type: application/octet-stream

…binary data…
```

Everything here is built using simply `StringBuilder`.

We are working with multi-tiered applications. This is how I convert an Image into `Base64String` to pass it along to the final tier:

```
Dim image As Image = image.FromFile("samplecheck.jpg")
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
oDeposit.Image = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())
```

which works fine I believe and then in the final tier where the post data is being built:

```
oPostData.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData)))
```

As you can see the `ContentType` should be `octet-stream` but I am getting API specific error which I am thinking because of the all these binary conversion stuff but I need to confirm all these steps I showed you is correct. Any suggestions?

**Note:** You may wonder why I am doing this like that but it is their stupid API's fault and now I have to follow it.

Comment: Can't you simply do `oPostData.Append(oDeposit.Image)`?

Comment: Having to generate your own multipart form post seems like a lot of wasted time, can you not use `HttpWebRequest` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. You shouldn't use a `StringBuilder` to store binary data.  You need to use one of the raw byte writers.
2. `Convert.FromBase64String` returns a `byte[]`, but it's not a byte array of ASCII data.  Therefore you shouldn't call `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`

Take a look at this other question to see how to build this POST data using the correct binary writers: [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)